# google map marker is not pinning properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

```
Code:

var dest1 = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
var request = {
  origin:start,
  destination:dest1,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
}

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay1.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

I am finding a location using google API and then calculating the distance between the searched place and the particular hotel which is coming from my data base, In image you can see i have searched for route map and distance for "Leela Palace Bengaluru, HAL Airport Road, ISRO Colony, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" to my hotel which is coming from data base,as you can see the marker is not exactly pinning on leela palace instead it is showing next to the leela palace that is marked as B in image. I don't know where exactly i have done wrong it would be great if someone can help me with this thank you

[Map response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iS2K.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Leela Palace Bengaluru, HAL Airport Road, ISRO Colony, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" is a place, not a postal address.  When you send that string to the geocoder you get a result for "Leela Palace Rd, HAL 3rd Stage, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India (12.9619947, 77.64936599999999)"

- [The geocoder is for postal addresses.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)
- [The Places API/library is for places.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

The distance service uses the geocoder for strings, if you give it a place ID, it will use that for the destination.

Using the [place id finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder), the place id for "Leela Palace Bengaluru" is:

> The Leela Palace Bengaluru
>
> Place ID: ChIJ3ZvKfAYUrjsRGuckzDe-GxE
>
> 23, HAL Airport Rd, ISRO Colony, Domlur, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India

You can use that for the destination of the DirectionsService.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cdhxq2cp/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var start = "Jogupalya, Karnataka, India";
  var dest1 = {
    placeId: "ChIJ3ZvKfAYUrjsRGuckzDe-GxE"
  };
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: dest1,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay1 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay1.setDirections(response);
      map.setCenter(response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location);
      map.setZoom(16);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Since i am finding the distance between two places when clicked on hotels i need a place ID from API how do you get that, your code works fine for static place ID, i am not getting the destination place ID from google API

Comment: You can use the places API/library to get the place ID.  What does "clicked on hotels" mean?  How do you dynamically choose that?  Note: This is probably another question.